# If I come from UK and I have travellers cheque how can I convert it at Mumbai airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, uk-citizens, exchange

I am British citizen and I have a travellers cheque of 30000 thousands euro. How can I convert my travellers cheque into Indian rupees at Mumbai airport? What are the rules and regulations?

If I can't have any cash with me both Indian rupees and euro, what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Make sure you have a really good story of WHY you are carrying that amount in cash (or equivalent). You will have to declare it both when exiting the  UK and when entering India and that is very likely to get you an extra round of questioning.

Comment: 30000 thousands = 30 million?!

Answer (score 5):

First, you will need to declare, **before** leaving the UK, that you hold more than 10000₤ in travellers' checks and that you are leaving with them

HMRC [state](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-cash-into-uk) :

> You must declare cash of £10,000 or more to UK customs if you’re carrying it between Great Britain (England, Scotland and Wales) and a country outside the UK.

Which includes travellers cheques

---

For India, the [Customs Guide for Travellers](https://www.indembassyuae.gov.in/pdf/trvler-guide_ason05feb2015.pdf) state :

> Any person can bring into India from a place outside India foreign exchange without any
> limit. However, declaration of foreign exchange/currency is required to be made in the
> prescribed Currency Declaration Form in the following cases:
>
> - (a) Where the value of foreign currency notes exceeds US$ 5,000/- or equivalent
> - (b) Where the aggregate value of foreign exchange (in the form of currency notes, bank
>   notes, traveler cheques etc.) exceeds US$ 10,000/- or its equivalent

You will need to take the **red** customs channel on arrival at Mumbai and declare accordingly

---

To cash them, you can cash them at any location mentionned in the [Traveleres Cheques Exchange Locator](https://travelers-cheques.americanexpress.com/en-in/travel/travelers-cheques/locator)

Comment: I'm guessing that most of the places that exchange travellers cheques will not exchange 30,000 Euros in one go.

Comment: And places at airports that change funds from one currency (here, EU €) to another currency (here, Indian Rupees) do so with very high transaction fees. Thirty thousand Euros would generate a lot of fees.